# Renaming file from UI

Tags: files, 14.10, rename

I can not rename files from the UI on my Ubuntu installation (14.10), it does, however, work from the terminal with the mv command. What happens is: when I right click on the file, then choose "rename" the file then appears to be selected but typing produces no effect at all.

I tend to find this rather frustrating, as far as worflow is concerned, renaming files with extensive names in the terminal is obviously a pain, and terribly slow on top of it...

How could I bring back to life my simple and convenient right-click > rename file ??

Thanks in advance for your kind answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a workaround for this problem in my Ubuntu installation (14.10).

Type the following command in terminal, now you will be able to rename files in UI.

```
$ nautilus
```